# How to: Run the .timeout operator only one time per presenting a view controller

Tags: swift, observable, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I am working with the following variable `gameTimeout` its a newly created observable from `game` with a timeout operator attached. I am looking for a solution to this `.timeout` operator running continuously..

```
 let gameTimeout = game.timeout(3, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
```

```
Observable.amb([gameTimeout, game])
        .subscribe(onNext: { (error) in
            print("pass")
        },
                   onError: {err in self._alertMessage.onNext("There was an error loading the game."); print("error \(err)")}
            )
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

I need it to only run once per (presenting a view controller). The code above currently will continue to run over and over again.. what should be changed to limit how many times the code gets executed?

Answer (score 0):

By itself it doesn't look like it would run multiple times unless you subscribed multiple times.  Where is this code?  Are you sure it's not subscribing multiple times?

Comment: .amb waits for an Observable to emit and unsubscribes from the others. gameTimeout emits currently because my game observerable "times out"... it doesn't emit an event... So that code is functioning how it should the problem is when onError is called, after dismissing the alert message gameTimeout emits again causing onError to be called once more.

Comment: to add on, I am unsure why that happens... currently "game" is being forced to timeout but even when it isnt gameTimeout emits starting the whole process again.

Comment: That's why I'm questioning if you are actually subscribing more than once.   Add `.debug` between `amb` and `subscribe` calls and see what spits out.  Is this code in a place that can run more than once like `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: running the debug now. my apologies! Code is in the middle of a class file not anywhere that would run it more than once like `viewDidAppear`